# redirect CreateProcess output to Shared Memory created Using CreateFileMapping VC++

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, createprocess

I have a Main VC++ application which is creating the shared memory as in below code:

```
if (m_hMapFile == NULL)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structSecurityAttr = { 0 };

    m_hMapFile = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, &structSecurityAttr, PAGE_READWRITE | SEC_COMMIT, 0, BUF_SIZE, (LPCSTR)(LPCTSTR)szName);

    if (m_hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        CString strError;
        strError.Format(_T("%lu"), dwError);
        return FALSE;
    }

    pSharedMemBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(m_hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    if (pSharedMemBuf == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    //Initialize the Shared Memory.                          
    ZeroMemory((void *)pSharedMemBuf, BUF_SIZE);
}
```

From a thread of this main process I am mapping to the shared memory as below:

```
if (m_hMapFile == NULL)
{
    //Open the Named Shared Memory 
    m_hMapFile = OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_COPY, TRUE, (LPCSTR)(LPCTSTR)szName); //FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS
    if (m_hMapFile == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Get the Shared Memory Buffer Pointer.
    pSharedMemBuf = (LPTSTR)MapViewOfFile(m_hMapFile, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_COPY/*FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS*/, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE);

    DWORD error = GetLastError();

    //If Shared Memory Buffer is NULL then return the control
    if (pSharedMemBuf == NULL)
    {
        CString strSize;
        strSize.Format(_T("Error is %d"), error);
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to redirect the output of the `CreateProcess` call to this shared memory. I am giving the FileMapping's `STARTUPINFO` as below:

```
si.hStdOutput   = m_hMapFile;
si.hStdError    = m_hMapFile;
```

Then creating the process as below:

```
CreateProcess( NULL, szCombinedCmd, &saAttr, NULL, TRUE, 
    dwCreateFlags, NULL, pszCurrentDirectory, &si, &pi );
```

But, When I am trying to read the shared memory I am not getting the output into the buffer. Please help me how to achieve this.

Comment: You engage in wishful thinking. You can't put any odd handle into `hStdOutput` - only a handle that would be valid in a `WriteFile` call. File mapping is not such a handle. [Redirect standard output to a pipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx), read data from that pipe, then write wherever you want, whether shared memory or otherwise.

Comment: Thanks. it resolved my issue.